# Making the UINavigationBar Shorter

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationbar

I have seen several apps that have shorter `UINavigationBar`. Like the `StackOverFlow` iOS app.

How do we achieve this? 
[image: example screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open several apps with navigation bars, you can see your statement is wrong when double-tapping the home button (to see them lined up nicely).

Compare Facebook, Whatsapp, YouTube, Pages, and Messages for example, they're all the same size. So unless they're all shrunk to the same size, I'd say they're not shrunk at all !

Now on top of that I suggest that you don't "change" your navigation bar too much, as it is a strong pivot point for your user and changing it would be "disturbing". Customize it to your will but have some limits.

If you just want to reduce it's height, I think you can simply use the navigationbar properties :

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar setFrame:<#(CGRect)#>
```

or

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height = //yourFloatValue.
```

And that should do it !

Comment: That second code example won't compile. You can't explicitly set the `height` property on a CGRect.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{ 
   CGRect temp=self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;
   [self.navigationController.navigationBar setFrame:CGRectMake(temp.origin.x, 40, temp.size.width, temp.size.height)]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, I don't believe that you can edit the hight of navigation Bar (For UX purposes). But you can hide it and create your own custom view and place it on top of the screen.

You can use this code to hide the navigation bar

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
```

and you create your own custom view like follows

```
CGRect barFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 65);
UIView *customeBar = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:barFrame];    
[self.view addSubview:customeBar];    
UIButton *navButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[navButton addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[navButton setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[navButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
navButton.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 56.0, 56.0);
[customeBar addSubview:navButton];
```

Comment: @annu There was a copy paste issue but it is fixed. If there is anything else that makes the above code as not proper code please explain.

Comment: @Cmsoll an user have no idea about copy paste mistakes so whatever write in coding should be proper.

Comment: @annu Actually I forgot to thank you for informing me of the issue